# What's the best way to migrate data from PostgreSQL to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, rubygems

I am a rails developer. To move sites to heroku, I need to migrate data from MySQL to PostgreSQL. To do that, I use mysql2psql gem which works fine.

Sometimes, I need to move back from PostgreSQL to MySQL. I wish there was psql2mysql. Sadly, I can't find such one. What's the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: Why are you developing on MySQL if you're deploying on Postgres?

Comment: Oh, That's exactly what I needed. Thanks. I'll close this post.

Comment: @Denis: Originally I deployed on non-Heroku server and migrated it to Heroku.

Comment: A tip: I work with MySQL, Oracle and PostgreSQl, and I use all this one with a software called Navicat. It has a tool for migration between databases. I hope this help you.